# Retain list view scroll position

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list fragment and a detail fragment. After scrolling the contents of the list view, on click of any item, it redirects to  the detail fragment. On return from the detail fragment, my list fragment should retain the scroll position. I tried this: But its reloading the list fragment:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mFirstVisiblePosition = mListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        // get offset
        View v = mListview.getChildAt(0);
        mTopOffset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        outState.putInt("currentScrollPOsition", mTopOffset);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

I'm saving the list scroll position and in on create I'm retrieving it:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTopOffset = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentScrollPOsition");
            mListview.setSelectionFromTop(mFirstVisiblePosition, mTopOffset);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public RssAdapter(Context context, List<Item> itemsList) {

        super(context, R.layout.news_items, itemsList);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private static class Placeholder {
        TextView Textview1, Textview2;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Placeholder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new Placeholder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_items, parent, false);
            holder.Textview1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.Textview2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.date);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Placeholder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Item currentItem = getItem(position);
        if (currentItem != null) {
            String title = currentItem.title;
            holder.mTitleTextview.setText(title);

            String date = currentItem.pubDate;
            holder.mDateTextview.setText(date);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No item to display",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

But its not working..Can anyone help me.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: show listview adapter.

Comment: means...sorry I didn't get you

Comment: please show your listview adapter

Comment: I updated my question adding adapter

Answer (score 0):

Save the first visible position and the top offset:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mFirstVisiblePosition = mListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    // get offset
    View v = mListview.getChildAt(0);
    mTopOffset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
    outState.putInt("firstVisiblePosition",mFirstVisiblePosition); // Save first visible position
    outState.putInt("currentScrollPOsition", mTopOffset);
}
```

Then, restore the first visible position too:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTopOffset = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentScrollPOsition");
        mFirstVisiblePosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("firstVisiblePosition"); // restore first visible position
        mListview.setSelectionFromTop(mFirstVisiblePosition, mTopOffset);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working...I should write it in the fragment itself right?

Comment: Yes, in the fragment. Try doing the restoring in onActivityCreated instead of onCreate.

Comment: Do i need to add this statement: onRetainSavedInstanceState();  ?

Comment: I debugged & checked. When it comes back from another fragment, list fragment gets recreated and it doesn't enter into this statement:if (savedInstanceState != null) {}..That y its loading again..What shall i do for this?

Comment: What do you do to return to the previous fragment? Could you show this part of the code?

Comment: I found this solution, maybe it helps you: http://michaelcarrano.com/blog/maintain-listview-position-in-android-application

Comment: i mean When i click a item of my list fragment, it redirects me to the next fragment.On return from that fragment, list fragment should retain its state.But saved instance state is always null